# Fastest Possible python code that can replace this function

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization

I am trying to optimise a function so it can work on a much larger dataframe.
I have a dataframe (called test_data)  that looks like this

[image]

To create a toy example I have filtered this dataframe like so:

```
value_list = ["DDD","MMM","AAPL","MSFT","AMZN","TSLA"]
test_data2 = test_data[test_data['Asset'].isin(value_list)]
```

I have written a basic function to generate the required output:

```
def generate_stock_price_dataframe():
    price_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    for stock in test_data2['Asset'].unique():
        data = pd.DataFrame(index = test_data2.index.unique())
        data[stock] = pd.DataFrame(test_data2.query("Asset==@stock")['Price'])
        price_dataframe = pd.concat([price_dataframe,data],axis=1)

    stock_price_data  = price_dataframe
    return stock_price_data
```

and this gives the required output.

[image]

This works nicely for the toy example with only a few assets.
However, When I run this with the full dataframe with 1000's assets...it just doesn't work.

Wheres the best place to start to speed this up?

Thank you

EDIT: Here is some code to recreate the question.

```
assets = ['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','AMZN','AMZN','AMZN','AMZN','AMZN',]
dates  = ['05/01/2021','05/02/2021','05/03/2021','05/04/2021','05/05/2021','05/01/2021','05/02/2021','05/03/2021','05/04/2021','05/05/2021','05/01/2021','05/02/2021','05/03/2021','05/04/2021','05/05/2021']
prices = range(1, 16)

test_data2 = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
test_data2['Asset'] = assets
test_data2['Price'] = prices

df = generate_stock_price_dataframe()
df.tail()
```

Comment: If I understand you right, do you want to pivot the table?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input (in text form) and example output?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. I have added some code to help recreate the issue and desired output. Just trying to learn how to make that function as efficient as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
df = test_data.pivot(columns='Asset')
```

**Output**

```
            Price
Asset       AAPL    AMZN    MSFT
05/01/2021  1       11      6
05/02/2021  2       12      7
05/03/2021  3       13      8
05/04/2021  4       14      9
05/05/2021  5       15      10
```

If we want to drop the `Price` from Multilevel Columns and the columns axis name `Asset`.

```
df = test_data.pivot(columns='Asset').droplevel(0,1).rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
df
```

**Output**

```
            AAPL    AMZN    MSFT
05/01/2021  1       11      6
05/02/2021  2       12      7
05/03/2021  3       13      8
05/04/2021  4       14      9
05/05/2021  5       15      10
```